# how to display this in jQuery live click

Tags: jquery

Could someone help me out converting this into a .live click?

```
<input class="productSubmitInput" name="AddToCart_Submit" type="submit" value="Add to Cart" onclick="AddToCart(26483,3123041,'',4,false);return false;">
```

Theres an AddToCart function on the onclick I need to run with the .live jquery function and I can't understand how to convert it

Comment: Im not sure what youre trying to achieve here, why does the click event need to change to a live event? After understanding that, I'll write something up that will take inputs as i assume you have many of these add to cart buttons on the same page, and need to be somewhat dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using a *really* old version of jQuery you should not use the `.live()` method at all. If using version 1.7 or later use the delegated form of `.on()`; if using older than 1.7 but newer than 1.4.2 use `.delegate()`.

```
$(document).on("click", ".productSubmitInput", function() { })
```

is equivalent to

```
$(".productSubmitInput").live(function() { })
```

...except better because it is more efficient and more flexible. Ideally instead of `$(document)` you'd do `$("#someForm")` where `"#someForm"` is the form that your buttons are in.

Having said that, following is one way to convert your code. I'll assume that the arguments you pass to the `AddToCart()` function are specific to each button, so you'd still need to associate them with the button somehow - I'll use `data-` attributes:

```
<input class="productSubmitInput" name="AddToCart_Submit" type="submit"
       value="Add to Cart"
       data-param1="26483" data-param2="3123041"
       data-param3="" data-param4="4" data-param5="false">
```

Then, having removed the inline `onclick=` attribute you'd do the following in a script block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // $(document).on("click", ".productSubmitInput", function() {
    // OR, better
    $("#yourFormIdHere").on("click", ".productSubmitInput", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        AddToCart( $this.data("param1"), $this.data("param2"), $this.data("param3"),
                   $this.data("param4"), $this.data("param5") );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Of course if some of those `AddToCart()` parameters are the same for all buttons then you can put them directly into the JS rather than storing them as attributes in the HTML, for example if the last parameter is always `false`:

```
    AddToCart( $this.data("param1"), $this.data("param2"), $this.data("param3"),
               $this.data("param4"), false );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an ID or add a function to the onclick statement that will run .live such as:

```
<input class="..." onclick="live(this)">
```

and the JS:

```
function live(object)
{
    $(object).live(whatever you do here);
}
```

Comment: [jQuery's `.live()` method](http://api.jquery.com/live) attaches event handlers, so you wouldn't call it from within another event handler like that.

Comment: The `onclick="live(this)"` is referencing the JS function, not the `.live` function. Function name can be changed to whatever you want.

Comment: I know that. What I'm saying is that there is no point calling a function from an element's inline `onclick=` handler only to have that function use jQuery's `.live()` with the _same_ element to bind another click handler. The next time you clicked that element both your function and the one bound with jQuery's `.live()` would be called, but your function would of course call `.live()` again binding yet another handler...

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="formId">
    <input class="productSubmitInput" name="AddToCart_Submit" type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</form>
```

```
$('#formId').submit(function( e ){
   e.preventDefault();
   AddToCart(26483,3123041,'',4,false);
});
```

Or a replacement for the deprecated `.live()` method:

```
$('#formId').on( 'click', 'input[name="AddToCart_Submit"]', function( e ){
   e.preventDefault();
   AddToCart(26483,3123041,'',4,false);
});
```